# React native app crashes in iOS release mode only

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, react-native, expo

I am getting the following error when the app run on release mode.
This crash happens when the time of app launching in simulator

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RCTFatalException:
> Unhandled JS Exception: TypeError: undefined is not an object
> (evaluating 't.insertRule=function(t,n){return
> t<=this.length&&(this.rules.splice(t,0,n),this.length++,!0)}')',
> reason: 'Unhandled JS Exception: TypeError: undefined is not an object
> (evaluating 't.insertRule=function(t,n){return
> t<=this.length&&(this.rules.splice(t,0,n),this.length++,!0)}'), stack:

At the same time this app working fine on debug mode.

Can you help me how to solve the issue appeared in release mode?

Answer (score 2):

We have analyzed each and every library in the app and it is using 'ThemeProvider' package.

It should be imported like the following into the mobile base app.

```
import { ThemeProvider } from "styled-components/native";
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an uncaught exception in your js bundle code. You have to fix it also for debug mode. But in release mode, uncaught exception triggers a crash.